# Dynamically display alt text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unicode

I'm trying to better wrap my head around state with react and this is a prime example if you ask me.

By dynamic I mean: render the output below simultaneously as entered in the form.

```js
class Demo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            input: "",
            output: "",
        }
    }

  render() {

    const smallCaps = {
      'a' : 'ᴀ',
      'b' : 'ʙ',
      'c' : 'ᴄ',
      'd' : 'ᴅ',
      'e' : 'ᴇ',
      'f' : 'ғ',
      'g' : 'ɢ',
      'h' : 'ʜ',
      'i' : 'ɪ',
      'j' : 'ᴊ',
      'k' : 'ᴋ',
      'l' : 'ʟ',
      'm' : 'ᴍ',
      'n' : 'ɴ',
      'o' : 'ᴏ',
      'p' : 'ᴘ',
      'q' : 'ǫ',
      'r' : 'ʀ',
      's' : 's',
      't' : 'ᴛ',
      'u' : 'ᴜ',
      'v' : 'ᴠ',
      'w' : 'ᴡ',
      'x' : 'x',
      'y' : 'ʏ',
      'z' : 'ᴢ',
  };

  function strtr(s, p, r) {
      return !!s && {
          2: function () {
              for (var i in p) {
                  s = strtr(s, i, p[i]);
              }
              return s;
          },
          3: function () {
              return s.replace(RegExp(p, 'g'), r);
          },
          0: function () {
              return;
          }
      }[arguments.length]();
  }

  const input = 'this is a test'
  const style = smallCaps; 
  let outputt = strtr(input, style);
  console.log(outputt);

  return (
      <div> 
        <div>
          <Form
            style={{ width: 300 }}
          >
            <Form.Item>
              <Input id="input" placeholder="input text" />
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div>
      <div>
        Style One:
        <div>
          {this.state.output}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate that!

Eventually I'd like to be able to display multiple styles at once, but I first want to understand this.

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. Dynamically display what? What does 'dynmacally' mean in this case? You want to display text when a button is clicked?

Comment: @TKoL By dynamic I mean: render the output below simultaneously as entered in the form

Comment: You want what a user types in the 'input' field to be modified by your 'smallcaps' function, and display in your `{this.state.output}` area? As the user is typing in the letters each one by one?

Comment: @TKoL yeah, that precisely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your input changes, it fires an onChange callback, where you can get the value of the element to update the state:

```
const smallCaps = {
      'a' : 'ᴀ',
      'b' : 'ʙ',
      'c' : 'ᴄ',
      'd' : 'ᴅ',
      'e' : 'ᴇ',
      'f' : 'ғ',
      'g' : 'ɢ',
      'h' : 'ʜ',
      'i' : 'ɪ',
      'j' : 'ᴊ',
      'k' : 'ᴋ',
      'l' : 'ʟ',
      'm' : 'ᴍ',
      'n' : 'ɴ',
      'o' : 'ᴏ',
      'p' : 'ᴘ',
      'q' : 'ǫ',
      'r' : 'ʀ',
      's' : 's',
      't' : 'ᴛ',
      'u' : 'ᴜ',
      'v' : 'ᴠ',
      'w' : 'ᴡ',
      'x' : 'x',
      'y' : 'ʏ',
      'z' : 'ᴢ',
  };

class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: "",
      output: ""
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const text = (event.target.value);
    const changedText = strtr(text, smallCaps);
    this.setState({value: text, output: changedText});
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
        <h3>input:</h3>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <p>{this.state.output}</p>
      </div>);
  }
}

React.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('app'));

function strtr(s, p, r) {
      return !!s && {
          2: function () {
              for (var i in p) {
                  s = strtr(s, i, p[i]);
              }
              return s;
          },
          3: function () {
              return s.replace(RegExp(p, 'g'), r);
          },
          0: function () {
              return;
          }
      }[arguments.length]();
  }
```